# CryptographicException no line number in stacktrace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cryptography, adfs2.0

I was getting following exception in event viewer with ADFS 2.0 and MVC 4 app configured via Visual Studio's Identity and Access Tool, app running on IIS 7.5

```
Exception type: CryptographicException 
Exception message: Key not valid for use in specified state.
```

I cannot reproduce the error. It happens intermittently on our public website and I see it via event viewer.

Even though this is a single server deployment and no farm involved (except that ADFS has one primary and one proxy server), just for sake of it I enabled web farm cookies by reading this article http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites-4/

The above exception went away but this one appears now with same intermittent frequency:

```
Exception type: CryptographicException 
Exception message: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
```

There is no line number in the event viewer's stack trace. Any other exception in this app gives a line number, this one doesn't. How can I find out what piece of code is causing this exception if I don't have the line number? Like I said I cannot reproduce it so no use of debugging, or is it?

**EDIT**

I noticed there are TWO elements under the keys node in web.config. Don't I need just one?

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration> 
        <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
            <authority name="http://our-FS-server/adfs/services/trust">
              <keys>
                 <add thumbprint="abcd" />
                 <add thumbprint="efgh" />
              </keys>
            </authority>
        </issuerNameRegistry>
    </identityConfiguration> 
</system.identityModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that extra key entry in web.config was the cause. I removed one of them and haven't seen the exception in 3 hours. Earlier that exception was coming much more frequently. So maybe the solution IS enabling web farm cookies like Vittorio Bertocci pointed out in his blog post http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/28/running-wif-based-apps-in-windows-azure-web-sites-4/

It just took longer in my case because I had that extra key.